# Unwanted gaps in regex match

Tags: regex-group

I read a lot of US addresses from source documents which are unrelated and so I have to deal with many different layouts, with or without delimiting commas, multiple spaces, etc. I am finding one part of my regex pattern very troublesome and I am hoping I can get some help with it. With the following sample address:

101 N MAIN  TOWER ST   FORT NICK, SC 87345

I wish to match '101 N MAIN  TOWER ST' then capture 'FORT NICK, SC 87345'  in a separate group. The regex is ugly. Notice the irregular spacing of the text, and this is one of the better ones.

Here is the pattern I wrote:

```
\d+(\s+\b(e|w|n|s)\b)?((\s+[a-z]+)+|\s+\d+((st|nd|rd|th)\b)?){1}(\s+\b(ave|av|avenue|blvd|bnd|bend|ct|crt|court)\b){1,2}(\s+\b(e|w|n|s)\b)?(?=(\s+[a-z]+)+,?(\s*[a-z]{2}),?(\s*\d{5}(\-?\d{4})?))
```

for an easier read:

```
\d+
(\s+\b(e|w|n|s)\b)?
((\s+[a-z]+)+|\s+\d+((st|nd|rd|th)\b)?){1}
(\s+\b(ave|av|avenue|blvd|bnd|bend|ct|crt|court)\b){1,2}
(\s+\b(e|w|n|s)\b)?
(?=(\s+[a-z]+)+,?(\s*[a-z]{2}),?(\s*\d{5}(\-?\d{4})?))
```

I get a close match but not quite what I want. It does match the address correctly, that is, up to the street type. But then it captures the City only partly: Nick TX 87345. It doesn't catch 'Fort' which is preceded by a multi-space.

I totally understand if nobody wants to look at this, but if it's not as terrible as I think I would really appreciate some advice

Comment: At the beginning of the final line you have `(\s+[a-z]+)+`. As written, that group will only capture the last match of the string between the parentheses (hence `" NICK"` rather than `" FORT NICK"`). `((?:\s+[a-z]+)+)` will get you onto the next hurdle! Parsing street addresses is likely to continue to cause you immense pain so I wish you well.

Comment: Jesus, its a good challenge what do you intend to do with: 
((\s+[a-z]+)+|\s+\d+((st|nd|rd|th)\b)?){1}
Also another issue i see you are having is the example you gave is incompatible with the regex due to the capital letters

Comment: @motto  Yes, it is painful to tame - you got that right. I am aware that there is no one pattern that will fit all formattings so I layer my code so that I catch broad patterns at top, then less broad ones after. For example, I separate addresses that omit the street type from those that include it. Thank you for the solution. I am now go and sit and see if I can wrap my mind around the logic of it. I am not yet fully comfortable with non-capturing grouping

Comment: @Imeguras  First, I get text from disparate sources so I always have case-insensitivity turned on.

Comment: @Imeguras  First, I get text from disparate sources so I always have case-insensitivity turned on. As for the pattern: ((\s+[a-z]+)+|\s+\d+((st|nd|rd|th)\b)?){1}, it reads clearer with some breathing room: (  (\s+[a-z]+)+  |  \s+\d+((st|nd|rd|th)\b)?  ){1}  so you can see that there is a alternation with 2 types of address formats. The first is named street labels like james allen street - a name preceded by 1 or more spaces, all once or repeated.

Comment: @Imeguras  Then the other would catch numbered street labels like 102 street, optionally including ordinal endings like st, nd, rd, and th for 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 6th. The 1 at the end is to prevent the city from being caught as part of the street label. I am sure there are more elegant ways of doing that but that's why I'm a novice at regexes

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d+\s[ewnsEWNS]?\s[A-z,\s]+\s(?:ST|ND|RD){1})\s((?:[A-z\s]*,\s)?(?:[A-z]*\s\d{5}(?:\-?\d{4})?))$
```

Or

```
^
(\d+\s[ewnsEWNS]?\s[A-z,\s]+\s(?:ST|ND|RD){1})
\s
((?:[A-z\s]*,\s)?(?:[A-z]*\s\d{5}(?:\-?\d{4})?))
$
```

I tested it on regexr.

Im european and unused to american addresses, altough your question intrigued me i achieved the answer with that specific address you gave us. This is not a final answer(im in class) feel free to point out issues or problems with my regex and ill attempt to solve them

Comment: I turn case-insensitivity off so I don't have to list upper and lower cases. I also abbreviated the pattern for this post so I needed alternations because other options are multi-character (e|w|n|s|ne|nw|se|sw|ene|etc). The matches aren't necessarily anchored to the start or end of the text either. I am not sure the street name part of the address can be simplified the way you have it, and trying your pattern on a sample address, I didn't get a match at regex101.com.

Comment: US addresses long form: Street-Number, Pre-Direction, Street-Name, Street-Type, Post-Direction, Bldg: tag-number, Apt: tag-number, then City, State, Zip. Street number, name and type are required, everything else is optional. So a long address may look like: 100 SW Main Tower Lane W Bldg 100C Apt 12. My actual pattern is thus much messier than the version I presented in this post. Also, given that I read addresses from random sources, required elements are not necessarily provided. I run into many that omit the street type, grrrr

Comment: correction, I turn case insensitivity on